# What are good analytic tools for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I am looking for a way to track the navigation process of my users, as well as the number of clicks/user for each view, average screen time per/day/user, and so on.

I know I can do this programmatically but it doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Is there any software that covers all of this?

Comment: recommendations for tools are explicitly off-topic on SO

Comment: Yeah bit off-topic but look into [App Center analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) it should be able to accomplish most of what you'd want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio App Center provides multiple useful tools. It offers real-time diagnostic data, tracking of usage patterns, user adoption and a lot more engagement metrics with App Center Analytics. You can even use custom events to get the exact user behaviors you are looking for.

I've been using it for a while and so far i'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

AppCenter is the easiest to integrate with, it also allows you to export the data to ApplicationInsights on azure to do more with that data. There are some other options like Google Analytics (You have to install nugets on platform projects and implement them separately). You also have segment If you are interested.